# Convergence in Probability VS Convergence in Distribution Weighted Dice Example

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, dice

Typically, convergence in probability and convergence in distribution are introduced through separate examples.  I want to see if I understand their differences using a common example of weighted dice.

First I'll explain my understanding of the *random variable* and *observed value* notions.  I think of a *random variable* as analogous to a programming variable as it exists within the code text (which may or may not ever have been compiled).  I think of an *observed value* as analogous to the variable as it exists in memory while the program is running; it is the thing which has a specific numeric value visible in the debugger.  As an alternative analogy, an *observed value* references the result of a random event we see (i.e., "the coin landed heads"), while a *random variable* references the result of a random event an observer of a perpetually branching multiverse sees (i.e., "the coin landed heads in half of the branches and tails in half of the branches").

Assuming no objections to the above, suppose I roll a pair of weighted dice (recording the sum), then replace them with a new pair and roll the new pair (recording the sum), then replace them with a new pair, and so on.  What I want to say is that the *successive sums of each rolled dice pair* converge in probability to an *observed value* iff they eventually become and remain arbitrarily close to that value.  So if the first die in each pair lands on $2$ with a probability approaching $100\%$ and the second die in each pair lands on $5$ with a probability approaching $100\%$, or alternatively, if the probability distribution of the first die is arbitrary but I am always allowed to observe that $n$ has been rolled and then choose the second die in the pair to have a probability distribution sufficiently similar to a degenerate distribution localized at $7 - n$, in either case the sums of each rolled pair converge in probability to the *observed value* $7$.

By contrast, I want to say that the *successive dice pairs* converge in distribution to a *random variable* iff their probability distributions eventually become and remain arbitrarily close to the probability distribution of that *random variable*.  So if both dice are chosen to be more and more fair in each iteration of the process, or alternatively, if the probability distribution of the first die is arbitrary but I can always reverse engineer a probability distribution for the second die so that the probability distribution of the sum is sufficiently similar to a uniform distribution, in either case the dice pairs converge in distribution to a uniform *random variable*.

I often see it said that something can converge in probability to a *random variable*, but I wonder if (at least according to the above distinction) it would be more accurate to say it converges in probability to an *observed value* (the $x$ rather than the $X$ in $\Pr(X\ =\ x)$).  Is what I've said accurate?  If not, what is a single, simple example to highlight the difference between convergence in probability and convergence in distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In generality, the two modes of convergence describe the convergence of a sequence of random variables $X_n$ to a random variable $X$.

---

In the special case where the target $X$ is a **constant** $x_0$, the two definitions coincide.

- Suppose $P(|X_n-x_0|>\epsilon) \to 0$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Note that the CDF of the constant $x_0$ is a step function $F(x)$ that is zero for $x < x_0$ and one for $x \ge x_0$. If $x < x_0$ then $$F_{X_n}(x) = P(X_n \le x) \le P(|X_n - x_0| > \frac{x-x_0}{2}) \to 0.$$ You can similarly show that if $x > x_0$ then $F_{X_n}(x) \to 1$. Thus, the CDFs of $X_n$ converge to all continuity points of the step function CDF $F(x)$ of the constant $x_0$, i.e. convergence in distribution.
- Conversely, if the CDFs $F_{X_n}$ converge to the step function $F$ this implies $P(|X_n - x_0| > \epsilon) = F_{X_n}(x_0 - \epsilon) + (1-F_{X_n}(x_0 + \epsilon)) \to 0 + (1 - 1) = 0$, i.e. convergence in probability.

In particular, your first example is an example of both convergence in probability and in distribution.

---

When the target $X$ is not a constant, the two notions are different (you can find many [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1294652/43949) if you search for them). One particular technical distinction is that you can talk about convergence in distribution without specifying how the $X_1, \ldots, X_n, \ldots$ and $X$ are all related to each other; you can look the CDFs of each of them in isolation without regard to the dependence. On the other hand, convergence in probability requires one to have a common probability space where the $X_n$ and $X$ live; the dependency between these random variables must be specified. See the link above (and other posts on this site and elsewhere on the internet) for more discussion.